# Python custom scripting in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The index has the capability of taking custom scripting in Python, but I can't find an example of custom scripting written in Python anywhere. Does anybody have an example of a working script? One with something as simple as an if-statement would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple custom scoring query using python (assuming you have the plugin installed).

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script_score": {
        "lang": "python",
        "script": [
          "if _score:",
          "  _score"
        ]
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "track_scores": true
}
```

Comment: Just the custom scoring plugin for the python language @chimpsarehungry : https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-python

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [elasticsearch ML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/rH5bXVW7FA4/y0FrjrILO0sJ) -

> Luca pointed out that ES calls python with an 'eval'

[PyObject ret = interp.eval((PyCode) compiledScript);](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-python/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/script/python/PythonScriptEngineService.java#L84)

Just make sure your code pass through the `eval`.